# Parse API output in Python

Tags: python, f5

I'm new to python and I've been trying to parse the output of from an F5 API request and I'm struggling a bit. I would like to extract all the "name" and "destination" values and save those to a file. This should be a name and the corresponding IP address. From the output below, it would be:

test-account 10.1.1.1
test-account_443 10.1.1.5

I can extract the individual elements, but I'm struggling to figure out how to iterate over the output file so I can get all of the key values I want. I've cut the output short to make it easier to read.

```
parsed_json = json.loads(data)
destination = parsed_json['items'][0]['destination']
name = parsed_json['items'][0]['name']
```

This only extracts one key value from the whole output file. Many thanks in advance.

```
 {
        "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualcollectionstate",
        "items": [
            {
                "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualstate",
                "name": "test-account",
                "partition": "Common",
                "fullPath": "/Common/test-account",
                "generation": 1,
                "addressStatus": "yes",
                "autoLasthop": "default",
                "cmpEnabled": "yes",
                "connectionLimit": 0,
                "destination": "/Common/10.1.1.1:80",
                "enabled": true,
                "gtmScore": 0,
                "ipProtocol": "tcp",
                "mask": "255.255.255.255",
                "mirror": "disabled",
                "mobileAppTunnel": "disabled",
                "nat64": "disabled",
                "pool": "/Common/test-account",
                "rateLimit": "disabled",
                "rateLimitDstMask": 0,
                "rateLimitMode": "object",
                "rateLimitSrcMask": 0,
                "serviceDownImmediateAction": "none",
                "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "sourceAddressTranslation": {
                    "type": "automap"
                },
                "sourcePort": "preserve",
                "synCookieStatus": "not-activated",
                "translateAddress": "enabled",
                "translatePort": "enabled",
                "vlansDisabled": true,
                "vsIndex": 2,
                "rules": [
                    "/Common/redirect-http-to-https"
                ],
                "rulesReference": [
                    {
                        "link": 
                    }
                ],
                "policiesReference": {
                    "link": 
                    "isSubcollection": true
                },
                "profilesReference": {
                    "link": 
                    "isSubcollection": true
                }
            },
            {
                "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualstate",
                "name": "test-account_443",
                "partition": "Common",
                "fullPath": "/Common/test-account_443",
                "generation": 1,
                "selfLink": 
                "addressStatus": "yes",
                "autoLasthop": "default",
                "cmpEnabled": "yes",
                "connectionLimit": 0,
                "destination": "/Common/10.1.1.5:443",
                "enabled": true,
                "gtmScore": 0,
                "ipProtocol": "tcp",
                "mask": "255.255.255.255",
                "mirror": "disabled",
                "mobileAppTunnel": "disabled",
                "nat64": "disabled",
                "pool": "/Common/test-account",
                "poolReference": {
                    "link": 
                },
                "rateLimit": "disabled",
                "rateLimitDstMask": 0,
                "rateLimitMode": "object",
                "rateLimitSrcMask": 0,
                "serviceDownImmediateAction": "none",
                "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "sourceAddressTranslation": {
                    "type": "automap"
                },
                "sourcePort": "preserve",
                "synCookieStatus": "not-activated",
                "translateAddress": "enabled",
                "translatePort": "enabled",
                "vlansDisabled": true,
                "vsIndex": 3,
                "policiesReference": {
                    "link": 
                    "isSubcollection": true
                },
                "profilesReference": {
                    "link": 
                    "isSubcollection": true
                }
            }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. You can iterate over the "items" key and get the required information

**Ex:**

```
parsed_json = {
        "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualcollectionstate",
        "items": [
            {
                "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualstate",
                "name": "test-account",
                "partition": "Common",
                "fullPath": "/Common/test-account",
                "generation": 1,
                "addressStatus": "yes",
                "autoLasthop": "default",
                "cmpEnabled": "yes",
                "connectionLimit": 0,
                "destination": "/Common/10.1.1.1:80",
                "enabled": True,
                "gtmScore": 0,
                "ipProtocol": "tcp",
                "mask": "255.255.255.255",
                "mirror": "disabled",
                "mobileAppTunnel": "disabled",
                "nat64": "disabled",
                "pool": "/Common/test-account",
                "rateLimit": "disabled",
                "rateLimitDstMask": 0,
                "rateLimitMode": "object",
                "rateLimitSrcMask": 0,
                "serviceDownImmediateAction": "none",
                "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "sourceAddressTranslation": {
                    "type": "automap"
                },
                "sourcePort": "preserve",
                "synCookieStatus": "not-activated",
                "translateAddress": "enabled",
                "translatePort": "enabled",
                "vlansDisabled": True,
                "vsIndex": 2,
                "rules": [
                    "/Common/redirect-http-to-https"
                ],
                "rulesReference": [
                    {
                        "link": True
                    }
                ],
                "policiesReference": {
                    "link": True,
                    "isSubcollection": True
                },
                "profilesReference": {
                    "link": True,
                    "isSubcollection": True
                }
            },
            {
                "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualstate",
                "name": "test-account_443",
                "partition": "Common",
                "fullPath": "/Common/test-account_443",
                "generation": 1,
                "selfLink": True,
                "addressStatus": "yes",
                "autoLasthop": "default",
                "cmpEnabled": "yes",
                "connectionLimit": 0,
                "destination": "/Common/10.1.1.5:443",
                "enabled": True,
                "gtmScore": 0,
                "ipProtocol": "tcp",
                "mask": "255.255.255.255",
                "mirror": "disabled",
                "mobileAppTunnel": "disabled",
                "nat64": "disabled",
                "pool": "/Common/test-account",
                "poolReference": {
                    "link": True
                },
                "rateLimit": "disabled",
                "rateLimitDstMask": 0,
                "rateLimitMode": "object",
                "rateLimitSrcMask": 0,
                "serviceDownImmediateAction": "none",
                "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "sourceAddressTranslation": {
                    "type": "automap"
                },
                "sourcePort": "preserve",
                "synCookieStatus": "not-activated",
                "translateAddress": "enabled",
                "translatePort": "enabled",
                "vlansDisabled": True,
                "vsIndex": 3,
                "policiesReference": {
                    "link": True,
                    "isSubcollection": True
                },
                "profilesReference": {
                    "link": True,
                    "isSubcollection": True
                }
            }]
        }


res = []
for value in parsed_json["items"]:
    print(value["name"])
    print(value["destination"])
    print(value["destination"].split("/")[-1].split(":")[0])  #if you need only the IP.
```

**Output:**

```
test-account
/Common/10.1.1.1:80
10.1.1.1
test-account_443
/Common/10.1.1.5:443
10.1.1.5
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help! Exactly what I was looking for.